Material UI: center checkboxes in grid regardless of checkbox label length
I have a form with code:
<Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" alignItems="center" mt={2}>
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
        {playlists.map((playlist) => (
          <Grid item lg={4} md={6} sm={6} xs={12} key={playlist?.id}>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox checked={true} />}
              label={playlist?.name}
            />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
      <TextField
        name="comment"
        label="Comment"
        multiline
        sx={{ width: isLarge ? "80%" : "45%" }}
        margin="normal"
        color="secondary"
        InputProps={{
          startAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="start">
              <AddCommentIcon />
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        disableElevation
        color="secondary"
        startIcon={<VideoCallIcon />}
        sx={{ mt: 2, width: isLarge ? "80%" : "45%" }}
      >
        Upload Video
      </Button>
</Box>

Which renders like this:

I would like to make the margin of the left side of the left column equal to the margin on the right side of the right column so that the checkboxes are centered on the page.
I am able to accomplish this by setting the Grid item to have the align="center" prop although this disrupts the vertical alignment of the checkboxes - here is a picture for reference:

I would like the form to look like this (I brute forced the code with CSS although now the form does not work dynamically based on the user's screensize - this is only a reference of my desired result.

How can I adjust my container to achieve this?

Do you have this online to see it in action?

I can try to create a sandbox later today
